# What's the size overhead of git commits?

Tags: git

I have a repo where I store notes (using Obsidian, if you must know), and I commit frequently with small updates (with a script that runs automatically).

Today I realized that the actual contents of the working dir are about 2mb, while the `.git` directory is taking ~30mb. So this got me wondering, *how much storage overhead I am consuming by having many small commits, each with very few changes*?

In other words, is there an estimate of the storage overhead per git commit (that is, on top of the actual differential contents of the changes one is committing)?

Considering this information, I could change the script to commit less often, if that would actually make a difference to the size of the `.git` folder. Thanks.

Comment: Git stores entire files as they change, not diffs. So every commit to a file creates a copy of that file in a blob. The commit information itself is negligible in size. You have the future option to rebase commits into one, and git will forget/delete/garbage collect the intermediary change files

Comment: @AndyRay `Git stores entire files as they change, not diffs` ... What?!? Are you sure about this? Can you maybe point out some reference for this statement? I'm sorry but if this is true then I really had the wrong mental model of how git worked. Thanks!

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202012/experimenting_with_git_storage.html, head blown.

Comment: The object packs do add some compression, though. `The commit information itself is negligible in size` So I would like something more explicit than this?

Comment: How often do you do [maintenance](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery)? [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck), [`git gc --aggressive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)…

Comment: @a06e Yes this is a common git misconception. Subversion stores diffs, git stores whole files. Also important to note git doesn't store a copy of the whole repository, only if a file changes, a new repository _tree_ points to all the old files, and the new tree points to the new whole file that changed.

Comment: @phd Never done it. Thought this was automatic. Should I do it manually from time to time?

Comment: Ah wow. Just ran `git gc --aggressive` and my `.git` dir went from 30mb to 4mb!

Comment: I do it once a week during full maintenance-and-backup run. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance with which you can configure automatic maintenance.

Comment: @a06e check https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects